# Arduino based small LCD screen with camera video capturing

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

i have a idea to create a small screen which displays video recorded from arduino with camera. so camera will be back side of human and screen will be at near to eye. human can see the pictures from back side.

i have found https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29139/processing-ntsc-video-feed-for-spi-display

but its not give me a clear idea. is there any one who can advice me for that kind project?

Comment: What exactly do you need advice on?

Comment: the devices or any projects already done with this idea???

Comment: An arduino (at least the classic ATMEGA-based ones) is nowhere near fast enough for this task, and also lacks the necessary memory to hold even a single frame of reasonable resolution video.  One of the ARM-based boards also offered from arduino.cc might *barely* work, but overall you'd be better with at least a raspberry pi or something even more capable likely based on a smartphone SoC.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: You should post that as an answer - it's dead on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Arduino doesn't have anywhere near the processing ability to transcode video from a camera unless you had an abysmal frame rate and very low quality. Even then, you would have to add extra storage because the Arduino would be over capacity in a heartbeat.

I recommend converting this project to a higher powered board like the Udoo. I have the [Udoo Quad](http://www.udoo.org/) and it's beastly considering its form factor. You're going to need something a lot bigger than an Arduino!